# How can I use these lines more than once?

Tags: javascript

I got 3 buttons.

```
<button class="one"></button>
<button class="two"></button>
<button class="three"></button>
```

This is the JS part and my question is instead of writing 3 times, how can I add a function so that I can use it as many times as I need? Thanks for your help.

```
var openBtn = document.querySelector(".one");
var openBtnTwo = document.querySelector(".two");
var openBtnThree = document.querySelector(".three");
var hiddenBox = document.querySelector(".hidden-box");
       
       openBtn.onclick = function(){
    
        if(hiddenBox.style.display ==="none") {
    
            openBtn.innerText = "Close";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "block";
    
        }else {
    
            openBtn.innerText = "Learn More";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "none";
        }
    
       }

openBtnTwo.onclick = function(){
    
        if(hiddenBox.style.display ==="none") {
    
            openBtnTwo.innerText = "Close";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "block";
    
        }else {
    
            openBtnTwo.innerText = "Learn More";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "none";
        }
    
       }

openThree.onclick = function(){
    
        if(hiddenBox.style.display ==="none") {
    
            openThree.innerText = "Close";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "block";
    
        }else {
    
            openThree.innerText = "Learn More";
            hiddenBox.style.display = "none";
        }
    
       }
```

My question is instead of writing 3 times, how can I add a function so that I can use it as many times as I need? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Give the function a name and pass it (the name) to each `onclick`?

Comment: All 3 buttons will affect the same `hiddenBox` though? Did you mean to have each button have their own `.hidden-box` element?

Comment: event delegation is your best choice. https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the shared code to a function, and replace specific code with generic code that can be applied to all elements. In this case, if you want to reference each button when clicked, you can use `e.currentTarget`.

```js
function onClickHandler(e) {
    if (hiddenBox.style.display === "none") {
        e.currentTarget.innerText = "Close";
        hiddenBox.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.currentTarget.innerText = "Learn More";
        hiddenBox.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Then add a click event listener to the elements, like so:

```js
openBtn.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
openBtnTwo.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
openThree.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
```

Edit: I've removed the `.onclick` method since this **should not** be used ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick/6348597#6348597)), instead use `.addEventListener`. I've also replaced `e.target` by `e.currentTarget` as pointed out by @Roko C. Buljan.

Comment: (Nice answer.) I would not put your *"I'd also suggest"* as a *Post Scriptum*. There's not one single viable argument to use `on*` handlers on existing DOM elements.  *Always* use `addEventListener` - unless, as I said, you're creating a brand new Element from in-memory.

Comment: Also, always think first `Event.currentTarget` - and only if you understand that currentTarget is not the desired Element, only than use `Event.target`. There's only one use case to use `Event.target` - and that's when traversing with `.closest()` to self-or-ancestor.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the input, I've editted my answer to reflect both points which I 100% agree.